# mismatch vue js 3 nuxt js with vue-server-renderer

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I am trying to npm run dev my nuxt js vue3 project. And I get error: [image]

My package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.25.3",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.8",
    "vue": "^3.0.0-rc.8",
    "vue-server-renderer": "^2.7.14",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.7.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^8.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^13.2.0"
  }
}
```

How make it work in compatibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably replace

> `vue-server-renderer`+ `vue-template-compiler`

by

> `@vue/compiler-sfc` + `@vue/server-renderer`

Also, I'm not sure why you're using an RC version for Vue3, use the latest aka [`v3.2.45`](https://github.com/vuejs/core/releases) at the time of writing.

As for Nuxt, Nuxt2 is aimed towards usage with Vue2.
Nuxt's latest stable version for Vue3 is [`v3.0.0`](https://nuxt.com/v3).

---

At that point, if you are starting a new project, consider using [the CLI](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/installation#prerequisites) for such a purpose (don't forget to respect the prerequisites).